# How to exclude rows with multiple conditions and "not in" in SAS?

Tags: sql, sas

I have a doubt in a query, I thought the solution would be simple but I realized that it is not.
I have table A and the cod field is the main key.

| COD | CATEGORY | PRODUCT | IND | SOURCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Two | black | Y | ANEXO8 |
| 2 | Two | black | Y | ANEXO8 |
| 3 | Two | black | N | ANEXO8 |
| 4 | Two | red | Y | ANEXO8 |
| 5 | Two | red | Y | ANEXO8 |
| 6 | Two | red | N | ANEXO8 |
| 7 | Two | yellow | Y | ANEXO8 |
| 8 | Two | yellow | N | ANEXO8 |
| 9 | Two | green | N | ANEXO8 |
| 10 | Two | green | N | ANEXO8 |
| 11 | Two | pink | Y | ANEXO8 |
| 12 | Two | pink | Y | ANEXO8 |
| 13 | Two | pink | N | ANEXO8 |
| 14 | Two | gray | N | SAS |
| 15 | Two | gray | N | SAS |
| 16 | Two | gray | N | SAS |

What I am trying to get is to first filter out all rows that have the field "ANEXO8", then to exclude all rows that have the field PRODUCTequal to "black", finally to exclude all rows that have the field product equal to "red" only if the field IND is equal to "Y".

The resulting table would be equal to:

| COD | CATEGORY | PRODUCT | IND | SOURCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | Two | red | N | ANEXO8 |
| 7 | Two | yellow | Y | ANEXO8 |
| 8 | Two | yellow | N | ANEXO8 |
| 9 | Two | green | N | ANEXO8 |
| 10 | Two | green | N | ANEXO8 |
| 11 | Two | pink | Y | ANEXO8 |
| 12 | Two | pink | Y | ANEXO8 |
| 13 | Two | pink | N | ANEXO8 |
| 14 | Two | gray | N | SAS |
| 15 | Two | gray | N | SAS |
| 16 | Two | gray | N | SAS |

I have tried to perform a single query:

```
proc sql;
   create table test as                                                                            
   select * from A 
   where SOURCE = "ANEXO8" 
   and PRODUCT not in ("black")
   and (PRODUCT not in ("red") and IND ne "Y"));
run;
```

But I don't get the result I want, do you know what I could do, or maybe where am I going wrong?

Comment: what are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
proc sql;
   create table test as                                                                            
   select * from A 
   where SOURCE = "ANEXO8" 
   and PRODUCT not in ("black")
   and not (PRODUCT in ("red") and IND = "Y"));
run;
```

You have to be careful with how the parenthesis are actually influencing the negation

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is close but the last `and` should be `or`:

```
create table test as                                                                            
   select * from A 
   where SOURCE = 'ANEXO8' and 
         PRODUCT <> 'black' and
         (PRODUCT <> 'red' or IND <> 'Y');
```

This is simply a logic error.  Do note other differences:

- `NOT IN` seems over kill when "not equals" is sufficient.
- The SQL Standard string delimiter is a single quote not a double quote.
- The SQL Standard not-equals operator is `<>`.